# CodeIgniter function breaks with Javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, formatting

I'm using CodeIgniter form helper, and this is what it does:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

The code:

```
jQuery('#window-1').append('<?= form_dropdown('hfdata', $hf_arr, set_value('hfdata'), 'class="span3"') ?>');
```

As you can see, I'm using a PHP inside of a JS, when I do `<?= 'Test' ?>` it works.
So it seems like its related with the CodeIgniter function.

As far as i know this error message can be caused by unknown/wrong characters in the code, and from what I saw in the firebug, this CI function is generating text with tabs and line breaks... and that is my problem I guess.

I may be wrong, so please correct me if so.

I will appreciate any solution for this problem.

Comment: You are sending <?= as a string ;). Try something like this: jQuery('#window-1').append(<?=' form_dropdown('hfdata', $hf_arr, set_value('hfdata'), 'class="span3"') '?>); do you mean something like this? Btw, what do you want to do here?

Comment: @Laurence Is that what you say would be true, something like this wont work as well: `jQuery('#window-1').append('<?= 'My tekst<div class="yellow">Test</div>' ?>');` - but its working.

Comment: Php is executed on the server, this give html output. You browser will get that output and can do anything with it. From this point javascript can do his job. In other worths, it's impossible to generate with javascript a php file that gets executed . It's posable, but it's not safe to do. So what are you making?  Where are the <?= for in this case? Do you want to get the php output of a varible there? Or do you want to generate PHP code?

Comment: Btw, or do you want something like this: jQuery('#window-1').append( <?= form_dropdown('hfdata', $hf_arr, set_value('hfdata')); ?> 'class="span3"'); in this case form_dropdown is a php function that gets called. The content is placed in the append() function. The browser can now execute the javascript code.

Comment: Accoring to the http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html , it is safe, because the function is generating the HTML output , an `<select></select`> with options for the array.

Comment: @Laurence, in that case, the following error will be showed: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < `

Comment: CodeIgniter will generate here a form, so you need to call that function in PHP. The browser will receive the HTML and shows it to the user. So the solution is that you need to generate the javascript code with PHP. See the code from 1 command before.

Comment: the Unexpected token is hfdata. That is becouse you don't call the php function here. You just echo the function call.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you're screwing up your quotes and you need to change the way you're passing that last parameter to the dropdown.

```
$class = 'class="span3"';



jQuery('#window-1').append('<?= form_dropdown("hfdata", $hf_arr, set_value("hfdata"), $class) ?>');
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that too. But it seems to be impossible, because even when I removed that parameter and the code looks like this: `jQuery('#window-1').append('<?= form_dropdown("hfdata", $hf_arr, set_value("hfdata")) ?>');` an error still occurrs... So it MUST to be related with what `form_dropdown` functions returns - HTML code with the line breaks and tabs. That is no allowed from what I learned.

Comment: Run the page in Chrome, open the developer console (F12) click Network, then at the bottom XHR. You can view your requests and the responses there, the response will show you the page it's returning including any errors.

Answer (score 1):

To explain how PHP and Javascript works: Php is executed on the server, this give html output. You browser will get that output and can do anything with it. From this point javascript can do his job.

You are echoing the php function call to the users browser. Javascript can't call the php function. If you want to do this, then you need to make a php file call that returnes the result you want. But I guess there is an other problem. ( if you want to do this, escape the ' characters)

You need to execute the PHP code on the server. This will give a result. You send this result to the client. On the clients PC javascript will execute your javascript code.

If you want to generate with PHP the javascript code, then you can do something like this ( in PHP on the server!):

```
jQuery('#window-1').append('<?= form_dropdown('hfdata', $hf_arr, set_value('hfdata')); ?> ');
```

If this isn't what you want, then you are working on a design problem. Then it's a kind of dead end.

Comment: The server will replace: <?= form_dropdown('hfdata', $hf_arr, set_value('hfdata')); ?> with the form. So you will get output like this: jQuery('#window-1').append('<form>XXX</form>');

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself... As I said, it was caused by the HTML output that was returned from the `from_dropdown`.

The solution is simple, remove all unwanted characters like line breaks:

```
<?php
     $prepare = preg_replace('/^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$/m', '', form_dropdown('hfdata', $hf_arr, set_value('hfdata'), 'class="span3"'));
?>
jQuery('#window-1').append('<?= $prepare ?>');
```

Comment: Haha, I was thinking you were running the php code in javascript. So that you were outputting the php code.

Comment: Btw, your solution isn't a nice one ;). You will have performance lost and it isn't nice at all.

Comment: @lauw Have you any better solution?

Comment: Avoid CodeIgniter in this case? It isn't good that you need to do tricks like this. Maybe there is a hidden option that solves this problem.